# Get specific data from protobuf's message

Tags: serialization, protocol-buffers

I understand probuffer as a kind of serialization like JSON. I try to parse and extract GeneratedMessageV3 data(generated by probuf) in Java.

```
public final class ProtoBufMessage extends GeneratedMessageV3 implements ProductJoinOrBuilder {
                 /*Some kind of code autogenerated by protoc*/
}
```

In case of JSON, there is JsonPointer to extract specific data. As we know, we can use JsonPointer just defining the path of the data we want to extract.

```
JsonPointer jsonPointer = Json.createPointer("/books/1");
```

Is there any way to extract specific data from protobuf's message just like JsonPointer?

Or is there any official api do same job??

Comment: Do you mean that you want to determine this path at runtime? Just accessing data from the objects is done through the generated methods. Guessing by your json example, the generated code might look something like `message.getBooks(1)` or `message.getBooksList().get(1)` (at least in Java; other languages have different conventions).

Comment: Yup. I already implemented it like your comment. But, I am still wonder "Is there any easier way?"

Comment: "easy" is a complicated value judgement... I for example wouldn't say `.getBooksList().get(1)` is harder than `/books/1`. But do note that something generic like a path string will lose all the type-safety information that the generated code gives you.